# Counting letter frequencies from an input file

Tags: performance, f#

Out of pure curiosity, I decided to create a short F# script to calculate the letter frequencies based on the input file. Everything works smoothly and as I would expect. My questions regarding my code are as follows:

1. Does it conform to formal F# standards?

   I have done my best to keep it as functional as possible while maintaining a style similar to the most common one I've seen in example programs, but I am unsure if it is up to par.
2. Does it maximize F#'s capabilities while maintaining readability?

   This is as it seems, I am curious as to whether or not I have used all relevant and applicable F# functions inside the program (e.g. map). The portion I am most concerned about is this bit:

   ```
   Array.map (fun z -> 
                  let e, f = z
                  match count |> Array.tryFind (fun a -> let f,s = a
                                                         (e = f)) with
                  | Some x -> (e, Convert.ToInt64(snd x) + f)
                  | None -> z)
   ```

   I am unsure if my approach is proper, that `Array.tryFind` bit is especially horrendous, but I can't think of a better way to approach this. In addition, instead of the `tuple` type, should I  instead go for `records` or is there some other, more appropriate, solution that I am missing?
3. Are there any ways to optimize or simplify the program I have written?

   I have a decently powerful machine (i5 6600, 16GB RAM) and per FSI's `#time` directive, the program has the following footprint when processing ~10.1gb of text `Real: 00:14:30.479, CPU: 00:14:21.421, GC gen0: 208720, gen1: 96, gen2: 8`. I have had very little optimization experience whatsoever, so I am unsure if (by my calculations) 11.89mb/s is a good speed for such a relatively simple program.

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#time
#else
module LetterFreqCalc
#endif

open System
open System.IO

let explode (x:string) = [|for c in x -> c|]

let ToUpper (x:string) = x.ToUpper()

let numLetterInWord word =
    word
    |> ToUpper
    |> explode
    |> Array.countBy id

let sumTupArray (tupArr:(char*int64)[]) =
    tupArr
    |> Array.sumBy snd

let div (x:float) (y:float) = y/x

let mul (x:float) (y:float) = x*y

let rec CalcNextLine (reader:StreamReader) accumulator =
    match reader.EndOfStream with
    | true -> accumulator
    | false -> 
               let line = reader.ReadLine()
               let count = numLetterInWord line
               accumulator
               |> Array.map (fun z -> 
                                     let e, f = z
                                     match count |> Array.tryFind (fun a -> let f,s = a
                                                                            (e = f)) with
                                     | Some x -> (e, Convert.ToInt64(snd x) + f)
                                     | None -> z)
               |> CalcNextLine reader

let CalcLetterFreqOfFile (path:string) =
    let reader = new StreamReader(path)
    let start = [|for c in [|'A'..'Z'|] -> (c,0L)|]
    CalcNextLine reader start

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let occurences = @"dictionary.txt"
                     |> CalcLetterFreqOfFile

    let total = occurences
                |> Array.sumBy snd
                |> float

    let freqs =  occurences
                 |> Array.map (fun x -> (fst x, (let percentage = snd x 
                                                                  |> float
                                                                  |> div total
                                                                  |> mul 100.0
                                                 Math.Round(percentage, 2))))

    printfn "%A" freqs
    printfn "%A" (freqs |> Array.sortByDescending snd)
    printfn "%A" argv
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your `explode` function is almost just equivalent to `Seq.toArray<char>`. There's no need to have a `ToUpper` function just to call a method, especially if you're using it just once. And there is already a `.ToCharArray()` method anyway. I would recommend getting rid of both of those functions and using method calls instead: `let numLetterInWord (word:string) = word.ToUpper().ToCharArray() |> Array.countBy id`
- Similarly, it seems like overkill to have `div` and `mul` functions just so they can be used in a pipeline. Their usage later on can be replaced by a single lambda: `fun x -> x / total * 100.0`
- The `sumTupArray` isn't used and not really necessary. At one point you just do an inline `Array.sumBy snd` instead and that's fine.
- Regarding the portion you're concerned about: Note that you can do pattern matching in function arguments just like you can in a `let` binding. So this pattern...

  ```
  |> Array.map (fun z -> 
       let e, f = z
  ```

... can be replaced with `|> Array.map (fun (e, f) ->`

- The `Array.tryFind` can be replaced with `Array.tryFind (fst >> (=) e)` (using the function composition operator `>>` and the curried prefix version of `=`). If you don't like that you can still just use a lambda: `Array.tryFind (fun (f,_) -> e = f)`
- F# has its own more concise version of `Convert.ToInt64` called `int64`. Ironically, it's less type-safe than `Convert.ToInt64` because it also tries to convert other things like strings and can throw an exception if they're not valid. I would still use it in this case since we know an `int` can always be converted to `int64`.
- I think that most people don't use the style of indentation that you have used because it quickly uses of a lot of horizontal space. Instead of this, I would suggest starting a new line and indenting by four spaces. This can mean using a bit more vertical space, but it's worth it in my opinion.

With these suggestions applied, we end up with something a bit more concise and readable:

```
open System
open System.IO

let numLetterInWord (word:string) = word.ToUpper().ToCharArray() |> Array.countBy id

let rec CalcNextLine (reader:StreamReader) accumulator =
    match reader.EndOfStream with
    | true -> accumulator
    | false ->
        let line = reader.ReadLine()
        let count = numLetterInWord line
        accumulator
        |> Array.map (fun ((e, f) as z) -> 
            match count |> Array.tryFind (fst >> (=) e) with
            | Some x -> (e, int64 (snd x) + f)
            | None -> z)
        |> CalcNextLine reader

let CalcLetterFreqOfFile (path:string) =
    let reader = new StreamReader(path)
    let start = [| for c in [|'A'..'Z'|] -> (c,0L) |]
    CalcNextLine reader start

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    let occurences = @"dictionary.txt" |> CalcLetterFreqOfFile

    let total = occurences |> Array.sumBy snd

    let freqs = occurences |> Array.map (fun (e, f) ->
        let percentage = float f / float total * 100.0
        (e, Math.Round(percentage, 2)))

    printfn "%A" freqs
    printfn "%A" (freqs |> Array.sortByDescending snd)
    0
```

---

I just realised your original time was 14 minutes, not 14 seconds! Which explains a lot. I found a solution that I think is a good balance of fast and simple:

```
open System
open System.IO

let countByIdBig xs =
    let counts = Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_,_>()
    for x in xs do
        match counts.TryGetValue x with
        | true, c -> counts.[x] <- c + 1L
        | false, _ -> counts.[x] <- 1L
    counts
    |> Seq.map (fun (KeyValue kv) -> kv)

let CalcLetterFreqOfFile (path:string) =
    seq {
        for line in File.ReadLines path do
        for c in line do
            if Char.IsLetter c then yield Char.ToUpper c }
    |> countByIdBig
```

The `countByIdBig` is similar to `Seq.countBy id` but it counts using `int64` instead of `int32`. It uses a mutable dictionary for performance in a very contained way.

Then it's just a matter of getting a `seq` of characters to count and passing them to `countByIdBig`.

Comment: Excellent feedback, thank you. This project branched off from a completely unrelated project (Affine Cipher Solver), which is why little odds and ends like the ToUpper and line-by-line exist. I appreciate the solution you have provided, as it has helped me understand some of the facets of the F# language. I was, unfortunately, unaware of the StreamReader.Read() method as well. Thank you for your assistance, I appreciate it.

Comment: Hello, after applying your suggested improvements to my code, the time has dropped significantly from what it used to be. From `Real: 00:14:30.479, CPU: 00:14:21.421, GC gen0: 208720, gen1: 96, gen2: 8` to `Real: 00:09:40.527, CPU: 00:09:32.984, GC gen0: 177638, gen1: 64, gen2: 5`. The changes were mostly about how the code looks, not how it operates. Would the change to `numLetterInLine` really have made such a large difference? Why is the old way I did things slower by five minutes? I apologize for bombarding you with questions, but I'm very curious.

Comment: The difference probably comes from using .NET's in-built `.ToCharArray()` method instead of `[|for c in x -> c|]`.

Comment: @ChrisAltig I've added to my answer a simpler way of doing this which allows `int64` counts and is faster than my revised version of your code.